# Validation check for FTP in unix shell Scripts

Tags: unix

I m using following code :

```
ftp -v -n "$FTP_SERVER" << cmd

user "$USER" "$PASS"

cd $FTP_LOCATION

lcd $FILE_LOCATION

put $FILE_NAME
```

I need to check for is file is successfully FTP to another server or NOT !!

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Do `ls -l | grep $FILE_NAME` 
and check if the exit code(`$?`) is `0`